# the value of $M+u(1, 1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the domain $\Omega=\{(x,y): (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2<4 \}$ and let $\partial \Omega$ be its boundary. Let $u$ be the solution of the following Dirichlet  problem
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\nabla ^2u & = 0 && \ \ \textrm{ in $\Omega$} \\
u & = x && \ \ \textrm{ on $\partial\Omega$}
\end{alignat*}
If $M=\displaystyle\max_{(x,y)\in\Omega\cup\partial\Omega} u(x, y)$, then what is the value of $M+u(1, 1)$, where $(1,1)\in\Omega$. How do I find the value of $u(1,1)$? Thanks

Comment: A hint:  do you know the [mean value property for harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property)?  Incidentally, your penultimate line seems to be unfinished.

Comment: I only know that maximum attains at the boundary@user539887

Comment: So please read the linked Wikipedia article.